# How to change an element in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

What is the code that goes into: `void changeElem(String oldStr, String newStr)`?

I have a driver's class with:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create empty list
    SimpleLinkedList list = new SimpleLinkedList(null);

    // add some elements in the list in
    // reverse order so that list is sorted
    list.addElement("W");
    list.addElement("T");
    list.addElement("P");
    list.addElement("L");
    list.addElement("K");
    list.addElement("B");
    list.printList();

    System.out.println("change W to X");
    list.changeElem("W", "X");
}
```

I am supposed to make a new method called “changeElem” in another class where
`void changeElem(String oldStr, String newStr)` but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by manikanta is right; however, `changeElement(List list, String string, String replacement)` requires you to pass the List as a parameter, which means you can't use it in the context `list.changeElement("W", "X")`.

I'm assuming `SimpleLinkedList` is a Java class that you have implemented.

To use the method as `list.changeElement("W", "X")` instead of `changeElement(list, "W", "X")`, you need to add the method `changeElement` to the `SimpleLinkedList` class (which I think is actually your question).

Since actual implementation of the class isn't known, something like this:

```java
public class SimpleLinkedList {
    public void add(String str) {
        //This should be an existing method, for example
    }

    //Assuming this is the implementation
    private class Node {
        String data;
        Node nextNode;
    }

    private Node firstNode; //Should be set/unset in your add/remove method

    //New method. To keep the order of your list, iterate and replace individually
    public void changeElement(String str, String replacement) {
        for (Node n = firstNode; n != null; n = n.nextNode) {
            if (str.equals(n.data)) {
                n.data = replacement;
                break; //If you want to replace only one instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, when in doubt: Look at Java's source code. What you basically want to do is `find` the place where `str` is and then replace it.

That's almost the Java [`LinkedList#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) method, except instead of returning index when you find `str`, you're replacing it. [Java's LinkedList#indexOf() implementation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l602).

Answer (score 0):

We just have to add the replacement string at your intended location and then we should remove the unwanted string.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* // create empty list
     * LinkedList list = new LinkedList(null);
     */
    LinkedList listLinked = new LinkedList<String>();

    // add some elements in the list in
    // reverse order so that list is sorted
    listLinked.add("W");
    listLinked.add("T");
    listLinked.add("P");
    listLinked.add("L");
    listLinked.add("K");
    listLinked.add("B");

    changeElement(listLinked, "W", "X");
    System.out.println(listLinked);
}
```

```java
private static void changeElement(
        List list, String string, String replacement) {
    if (list.contains(string)) {
        // adding the replacement
        list.add(list.indexOf(string), replacement);
        // removing the unwanted
        list.remove(string);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Element not found to replace");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `SimpleLinkedList` implements the `List` interface and is at least Java 8:

```java
private static void changeElement(
    List<String> list, String string, String replacement) {
    list.replaceAll(s -> s.equals(string) ? replacement : s);
}
```

Of course you could call this 'Util' method from your `SimpleLinkedList` passing itself as the first argument.